# Can't change a python string

Tags: python, string

My mission is to get a string from a user, and then:

- Change every `A` character in the list to digit 1 ("1").
- Change every `B` character in the list to digit 2 ("2").
- Change every `C` character in the list to digit 3 ("3").

That's what I've done until now:

```
string = input("Enter a string: ")
for i in range(len(string) - 1):
    if string[i] == "A":
        string[i] = "1"
    elif string[i] == "B":
        string[i] = "2"
    elif string[i] == "C":
        string[i] = "3"
```

But when I run it, the interpreter gives me this error:

> line 4, in 
> string[i] = "1"
> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Does someone know how to make my code work?

Comment: Stings are immutable. Use methods to create new strings

Comment: Use `replace`...

Comment: Is there a way to do it without ```replace()```? because I didn't learn it...

Comment: Try `string = string[:i] + 'A'  + string[i+1:]`. And change the range to `(len(string))`

Comment: Good opportunity to learn `replace()` now?

Comment: Strings in Python are immutable. You need to create a new string if you want to make any changes to an existing string. To solve your problem idiomatically in Python:

    `string = input("Enter a string: ");
    table = str.maketrans("ABC", "123");
    print(string.translate(table))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that

```
user_row = input("Enter a string: ")
final_row = ''
for i in range(0, len(user_row)):
    if user_row[i] == "A":
        final_row += "1"
    elif user_row[i] == "B":
        final_row += "2"
    elif user_row[i] == "C":
        final_row += "3"
    else:
        final_row += user_row[i]
print(final_row)
```

Also

```
user_row = input("Enter a string: ")
user_row = user_row.replace('A', '1').replace('B', '2').replace('C', '3')
print(user_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable.Insted of that do this:

```
user=input()
user=user.replace('A',1).replace('B',2).replace('C',3)
```

Here replace replaces all the occurrence of a with 1 and etc